# Java sql.TimeStamp to Salesforce

Tags: java, datetime, date

I have a Java mapping that takes a field of type java.sql.Timestamp and insert it into Salesforce. Example of a field in the db:

> 2013-10-17 13:01:01

When it is inserted into Salesforce it looks like:

> 10/16/2013 5:00 PM

How do I fix it that it inserts the date as 10/17/2013 1:01 PM?

Here is how I set the field and getModifyD us returned as java.sql.Timestamp

```
clientNotesSObject.setType("Task");
caseSObject.setField("Client_Modified_Date__c", clientNote.getModifyD());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String emailMessageDate = "2015-05-29T16:35:26.000Z";

Code:

```
 Calendar emailMessageCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
 DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
 dateFormatter.setTimeZone(tz);
 Date emailMessageCreatedDate = dateFormatter.parse(emailMessageDate);
 emailMessageCalendar.setTime(emailMessageCreatedDate);
 sobject.setField("Email_Message_Date__c", emailMessageCalendar);
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with DateTime values in the Salesforce API they should be sent in ISO 8601 format with the UTC value.

Salesforce will change the value displayed in the UI based on the current users UTC offset.

Assuming your sample data is in the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) time zone, it would be:

```
2013-10-2013T13:01:01.000Z
```

See also: [Primitive Data Types - dateTime](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/primitive_data_types.htm#i1435039)