# Save Event to Salesforce without losing time

Tags: java

How to save an Event without losing time?
I have tried:

```
set("StartDateTime")(new Date())
```

`set("StartDateTime")(Calendar.newInstance())` -

> throws an error that value not of required type

Comment: this is covered here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76749/java-sql-timestamp-to-salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date()` isn't a `Date-Time`. You need to add the time element to the Date. You could, for instance, use `System.Now()` to get a new `Date-Time` for `Today()` that includes the current time element. Otherwise, you'd want to do something like:

```
Datetime myDate = Datetime.newInstance(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```

which would look like:

```
Datetime myDate = Datetime.newInstance(2016, 02, 1, 12, 30, 2);
```

Comment: Could you refer me to the class of Datetime? cannot find the one you mentioned. In java there are Date and Calendar.

Comment: Salesforce has an Apex [DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm%23apex_methods_system_datetime) class along with a Date class and a Time class which are all under the System namespace and can be found in the Reference Section of the Apex Code Developer's Guide. Just click the link above to go there.